# Automate WPF Application to Run

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I've created a WPF application which needs to have a button clicked to start, but was wondering what bit of code could I add so I can setup Windows Scheduler to run this application periodically. I know I have to make a change so the application is run using a command line but not too sure how I can get it to run and execute the method the button links too?

Cheers.

Comment: If it's automated like that and the UI is not being used why do you need it in the first place? You are describing typical functionality of a Windows Service, not a desktop app...

Comment: The customer has a requirement to either run the application with the UI and also wants to schedule the application to run periodically, that's why I create the wpf application with the UI but since I already have the code in the UI, I would prefer to make the small change to this WPF Application than create a new Windows Service.

Comment: have a look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736599/run-a-wpf-application-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: Given those requirements, I would put the scheduling parameters right in to the UI as user controlled parameters.  Then sleep as specified.