# Make a WPF Application in C# insert data automatically into database after expiration of a certain period

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I want a WPF Application in C# to automatically insert data (that I will specify) into SQL Server Database after the expiration of a period (A date duration which I will set). I had searched for this and the suggestion was to use " SQL Server Job Scheduling". I want to know if this fulfills my need or any alternative exists.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a small windows service or you can even run your WPF application as a windows service for which following post may be useful. Just check once.
[Run a WPF Application as a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736599/run-a-wpf-application-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: Sir I have not gone this far in WPF programming to be honest :). Can I have a more exact and easy way through which I could implement this. I have gone through the link you have posted but I cannot figure out what is there in for me.