# Use of console.readline()

Tags: c#, windows-services

now I have a C# application, which runs 24/7 with a timer, which elapse all 30 seconds and do anything.

I want to make this application to a windows service, to run in the background. But the service crash immediately..

My code:

```
public static System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      _timer.Interval = 30000;
      _timer.Elapsed += timerCallback;
      _timer.AutoReset = true;
      _timer.Start();
}
public static void timerCallback(Object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      // Do anything..
}
```

And the error:

> Windows could not start the Application service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

In the windows event viewer this message occured:

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Application service to connect.

But the error appear faster than 30 seconds?!

Any solutions to run the service??
Thanks

Michael

Comment: Can you post the code and the stack trace that is logged in the event log when it crashes?

Comment: Did you take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736599/run-a-wpf-application-as-a-windows-service

Comment: Windows Services are generally not designed to interact with the desktop.  Rather than using a `Console.ReadLine()` to prevent the service from stopping, just put in a continuous loop unless an error occurs.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips added my code and the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute the logic periodically within windows service,

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  base.OnStart(args);

  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.Interval = 30*1000;
  timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
  timer.Enabled = true;
  timer.Start();
}
```

---

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //put logic here that needs to be executed for every 30sec
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have until now, but the service fails onstart

Comment: better to debug the service, follow [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx) steps. see what is going wrong inside.

Comment: I think the error is that I don't have a OnStart function and the class is not derivated by ServiceBase?

Comment: How did you create yur windows service ?? You should add windows service from visual studio(simple as how you add class to a project). There is a item called windows service.

Comment: The application is a console application and now I want to convert it to a windows service.. is this possible? Or do I have to rewrite the whole program?

Comment: @ZerOne Like i said you need to create a class library and add a windows service and move the necessary logic from console app.